# How do I find the position of a linked s-expression from the original string it was parsed from?

Tags: c++, s-expression

I've been reading through the [sexp.h file reference](http://sexpr.sourceforge.net/refman/sexp_8h.html) in an attempt to generate helpful errors when parsing a lisp-like sequence fails because an operator or operand was not formatted as expected.

I am currently using the `cparse_sexp` function to parse a lisp-style expression into a series of s-expressions `elt` objects:

```
pc = cparse_sexp(
  (char*)expression.c_str(),
  expression.length,
  pc);
```

where `pc` is a pointer of type `pcont_t*` and `expression` is an `std::string`. I then use this `pc` pointer to look at the `elt` objects using `pc->last_sexp`.

However, if I run into a value that I don't know how to deal with, I'd like to be able to write something like this:

> ```
> Error was encountered at byte `123` in the vicinity of:
> (Operator Operand1 Operand2)
>           ^
> ```

Where the `(Operator Operand1 Operand2)` line is taken from the original `expression` string.

To achieve this I need to know the location from which the respective token was taken. I know I can see the `sbuffer` value within the `pcont_t` type, but that just gives me a pointer to the original string. `lastPos` is supposed to give me the current position, but it just returns the end of the string. How can I parse the string *as* I use it so that I can see where I'm at?

Comment: Unless you modify the parser, you probably can't. If you modify the parser, you can add a couple of fields to the [`elt`](http://sexpr.sourceforge.net/refman/structelt.html) structure that is a pointer to the source where the s-expression starts, and the length of the text of the s-expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok. Could I somehow modify it so that it parses token-by-token, rather than everything at once? Then when I encounter the error I'd have a best-guess using `pc->lastPos`?